# Detect if a list has ANY attachment in SharePoint CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013, csom

I need to read all items from a SharePoint-list including all attachments. This is the code:

```
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
   Dictionary<string, string> itemFilenames = GetFilenames(item.Id);
   if (itemFilenames != null && itemFilenames.Count > 0)
   {
      // [...]
   }    
}
private AttachmentCollection GetFilenames(id) { 
  List list=_context.Web.GetListByTitle("mylist");
  ListItem=list.GetItemById(id);
  var files=item.AttachmentFiles;
  _context.Load(files);
  _context.ExecuteQuery();
  return files;
}
```

Now 90% of my lists do not contain any attachments at all. Still: I try to retrieve the attachments for every single item which slows down the program massively.

So my idea would be to detect if the list has ANY attachment at all before trying to retrieve those for each item. So something like that:

```
var list=clientContext.Web.GetListByTitle("mylist");
if (!list.ContainsAttachments) return; // <-- What I want to do
foreach (var item in allItems) { ... }
```

Of course, the "if" - statement does not really work that way. But is there another method to find out if any attachment exists that would result in the wanted behavior?

**TL;DR:** I want to know if a list contains ANY attachment without looping through every item of that list

Comment: `list` is of Type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List`, NOT `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`. In other words: There is no LinQ-Solution for this

Comment: You still misunderstood. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List is called "list" but is no collection at all. Each item within list needs to be called using caml (which creates Soap-Requests in the background)
But never mind, @LZ_MSFT's solution seems to fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/sites/team");
var web = ctx.Web;
var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestStartWorkflow");
var query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
var items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items,i=>i.Include(item=>item.AttachmentFiles));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var flag = items.Any(i=>i.AttachmentFiles.Count>0);
```

Comment: I get an error on line -> ctx.Load(items, i => i.Include(item => item.AttachmentFiles));
ListItem does not contain a definition for AttachmentFiles